# Keyup event for text input box being capture by Google Chrome address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using the keyup event to fire the same event as clicking on the search button when a user presses the return key. When the search button is clicked it uses an Ajax request to load search results on the page.

The call works fine, but the keyup event is being captured when I press the return button in the address bar in google chrome after previously having focus on the input box, e.g. if the user types in a search query without pressing return, and instead goes to a new webpage using the Google Chrome address bar, when they press return on the address bar the search in my page is being submitted at the same time as the keyup event is being trigger even though the page, and certainly the input box, should no longer have focus.

JavaScript

```
$("#search-box").on("keyup", function(event) {
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
       $("#search-submit-btn").click();
   }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-append"/>
   <input id="search-box" type="text" />
   <button class="btn" id="search-submit-btn">Search</button>
</div>
```

I'm also using Twitter bootstrap to style the Input box, but I don't think this is causing the problem.

I've tested this page in Firefox and Safari without any issue. Does Google Chrome have a problem with the keyup event/is this a know issue? I'm struggling to find any information on the issue.

**EDIT**

I think I've solved my issue by using keydown instead of keyup. I've also added in a check if the element is still focused, but I don't think this makes a difference, since it still has the same affect with keyup.

```
$("#search-box").on("keydown", function(event) {
    if($("#search-box").is(":focus")){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#search-submit-btn").click();
        }
    }
});
```

This appears to be an okay solution for me, but it doesn't explain why keyup behaves so strangely in Google Chrome though. If anyone has anymore information about why keyup is this way in Google Chrome or if I am just doing something wrong, I'd be very interested to hear.

Comment: [Cannot replicate this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/87QMG/) (sans twitter bootstrap). so perhaps it's twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Perhaps it is. I am trying to replicate the issue without bootstrap myself. I think the problem is that the element still has focus for some reason when the user on the address bar, outside the page. I could be wrong, but frm my understanding $(selection).on("keyup", function(event) {} works only when the current selected element. So if should work when you click outside the page. Whether this is caused by twitter bootstrap or not, it seems like a Google Chrome issue since I don't have the same problem in other browsers.

Comment: Its definitely Chrome's issue

Comment: @ Ohgodwhy [Recreated without Twitter bootstrap.](http://jsfiddle.net/87QMG/1/). The alert will pop up before the page changes if you click on the input box and then click on the address bar, type in a search e.g. "test" and press return.